# Substituir ou tratar método obsoleto

Tags: android

Estou atualizando uma aplicação Android e me deparei com a seguinte situação:

- Possuo um sdk mínimo de 21 e target de 27.
- Um método que foi obsoletona versão 24.

Minha dúvida é a seguinte: qual a melhor ação para corrigir um método obsoleto?

- Substituir o método antigo pelo novo?
- Tratar para que o método antigo realize sua função para versões de android anteriores a 24 e o método novo realize as demais versões? (um simples if/else comparando as versões de api do celular com a do método.)

  `if{versão atual > 24){
      //Executa método novo.
  }else{
      //Executa método antigo.
  }`

Answer (score 4):

Depende.

1. A classe que tem esse método existe numa biblioteca de compatibilidade.

   - Use essa classe e mantenha a biblioteca actualizada.
2. A classe não existe na biblioteca de compatibilidade.

   - O método acrescenta funcionalidades nas versões mais recentes.

     - Recorra ao `if(versao)` e use o método correspondente.
   - O método não acrescenta funcionalidades.

     - Se o *target* for para manter, pode usar o método antigo.
     - Se o *target* é para ser actualizado para a versão mais recente, enquanto compilar pode usar o método antigo. Caso deixe de compilar e a condição 2 se mantiver, use `if(versao)`
3. O *minSdk* pode ser aumentado com impacto mínimo no alcance da aplicação.

   - Altere o *minSdk* e use o método novo.